# Can I set readOnly false when I use findById with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, database-replication

I have a problem with modifying data while setting database replication

Before DB replication, I get data that I want to modify using `repository.findById()` and then I modified the data.
But I realized that `repository.findById()` is set `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` in `SimpleJpaRepository.java` so that I can't modify the data even if I use @Transactional in my Service or `repository.save()`

Is there any other way to force `findById()` to connect by a write connection except by making custom method in the repository for findById?

+++)
I solved my problem! I wanted to use dirty checking for modifying datas and I realized that my setting about EntityManagerFactory was something wrong and I fixed it with a doc in spring.io (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference) I tried many times with many other developers posting but they didn't work for me, but it did. Thank you for giving me answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this,
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Section 5.7.1. Transactional query methods to be more specific
It says that @Modifying annotation can be used to override transaction configuration

> Typically you will use the readOnly flag set to true as most of the query methods will be reading ones. In contrast to that deleteInactiveUsers() makes use of the @Modifying annotation and overrides the transaction configuration. Thus the method will be executed with readOnly flag set to false.

Comment: I wouldn't use the documentation of version 1.0.0.M1. Use this one instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: My bad. Editing the link in answer. Thanks @Manuel

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change that flag!

1. Find the data
2. Edit data
3. Call JPA repository.save(newData) method with @Modifying to save the edited data in the DB

I.E.
@Transactional 
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE user SET points = points + ?1
WHERE id = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
int increasePoints(int points, Long id);